# Modal Controller not invoked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning angular js and i am trying to load a error modal, whenever any error occurs during rest call.

Below is my modal

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h1>This is the title</h1>
</div>'
<div class="modal-body">
    {{errormessage}}
</div>
```

Below is my parent controller under which i am defining the error condition

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, dataShare, $uibModal) {
    $scope.myInterval = 5000;
    $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
    $scope.active = 0;
    var slides = $scope.slides = [];
    var currIndex = 0;

    $scope.sendEnvName = function(data) {
        dataShare.sendEnvDetails(data);

        window.location.href = "query/queryboard.html";
    }

    $scope.addSlide = function (envName) {
        slides.push({
            text: envName,
            id: currIndex++
        });
    };

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/getEnvList")
        .success(function (data) {
            for (var i in data) {
                $scope.addSlide(data[i].envName);
            }
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'error/ErrorModal.html',
                controller: ErrModalInstanceCtrl,
                size: 'sm',
                resolve:{
                    errormessage: function () {
                        console.log('lllllllllllll')
                        return "Some error occured";
                    }
                }
            });

            var ErrModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, errormessage) {
                console.log(errormessage)
                $scope.items = items;

            };
        });

});
```

If i dont use resolve or controller, i.e. i hard code some string in the place of placeholder for error message, modal is loaded perfectly. I googled i found different answers regarding putting controller in quotes, but that doesnt helps either.

Please help me on this, not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: Try registering your modal controller. Like this: `angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ErrModalInstanceCtrl', ErrModalInstanceCtrl);` and then, pass `ErrModalInstanceCtrl` as a string to the `controller:` option. (Register the controller outside your current controller `CarouselDemoCtrl`)

Comment: Follow [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FyyOlJSj2XPAD0aax5Z) and tell me if it works in your case.

Comment: @GabrielHobold...it works when declared outside the CarouselDemoCtrl, does that means in angular we cannot have nested controllers ?

Comment: Yes. And I recommend you to use the same synxtax as I did in the plunker. Create a `function` and then use `$inject` to inject the dependencies and then register the controller passing the `function` name as the second parameter. This way you prevent further problems in minification (if you'll minify your js) and the syntax is better.  If you have some free time I reccomend reading [this style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), is built by the community and has a lot of good practices.

Comment: I'll post my answer below. Any doubts just ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the modal controller outside your current controller and then pass the name to the  `controller` property in `$uibModal.open` method.

Like this:

```
// REGISTER THE MODAL CONTROLLER HERE
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ModalInstanceCtrl);
ModalInstanceCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance'];
function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

    $scope.item = "I'm your item";

    $scope.ok = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}
```

Your controller:

```
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',  // The modal controller name ('ModalInstanceCtrl')
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            errormessage: function () {
                console.log('lllllllllllll')
                return "Some error occured";
            }
        }
    });
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FyyOlJSj2XPAD0aax5Z).